# How REPLACE the value of query parameter in vue-router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })
```

will generate URI like:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/register?plan=private&plan=public
```

if query parameter with key `plan` and value `public` already exists in `$currentRoute.query`.
So this manipulation will not replace `plan`'s, just turn the scalar value to array.

Now, how can REPLACE it?

Comment: Have you tried `router.replace()`?

Comment: From the docs: "It acts like router.push, the only difference is that it navigates without pushing a new history entry, as its name suggests - it replaces the current entry."

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Does not work... `replace` does not replace query parameter's value, just turn it to array even if value is same.

Comment: I just tried with `router.push` and it replaced the query. Are you sure there isn't something else that's the issue?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights Ever we use different version of vuex-router, or code expression is different. Would you please to append the code sample?

Comment: Here's how mine is setup: `const router = new VueRouter({ mode: "history", base: process.env.BASE_URL, routes });`

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, thank you for the code. Please append also `router.push` expression.

Comment: I used the same as you posted above, except I used `this.$router.push` as it was inside a single file component

Comment: @Daniel_Knights, strange... I'll continue the investigation tomorrow. Thank you for the messaging.

Answer (score 0):

The investigation result is `router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' } })` is wrong boilerdown of my code. Sorry for that.

```
router.push({ path: 'register', query: { plan: newValue } })
```

will replace the query parameter `plan`.